# didReceiveRemoteNotification take user to the correct view

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've got a chat application where my server sends out push notifications when a new message is send. The problem I'm having is how can i take the user to the correct view? Im sending a `channelID` in the push notification but how can i retrieve it and take the user to the actual conversation?

I'm using this code to detect when a push notification was clicked

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    if ( application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive || application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground  )
    {
         //opened from a push notification when the app was on background
    }
}
```

Comment: you only get userInfo data in push notification,check nslog(@"%@", userInfo);

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are sending `channelID` in push notification than you can retrieve `channelID` from userInfo dictionary.
As midhere said - 
**1)**  **When application is running in background** and **When application is running in foreground**
`application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:` method will called as below.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
if ( application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive)
     {
     //opened from a push notification when the app was on background

       NSString channelID = [[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"channelID"];
       NSLog(@"channelID->%@",channelID);
     }
  else if(application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive)
     {
     // a push notification when the app is running. So that you can display an alert and push in any view

       NSString channelID = [[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"channelID"];
       NSLog(@"channelID->%@",channelID);
     }
}
```

**2)**  **When application is not launched (close)** than `application:didFinishedLaunchWithOptions`method will called.

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  if (launchOptions != nil)
    {
         //opened from a push notification when the app is closed
        NSDictionary* userInfo = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
        if (userInfo != nil)
        {
            NSString channelID = [[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"channelID"];
            NSLog(@"channelID->%@",channelID);
        }

    }
     else{
             //opened app without a push notification.
         }
}
```

Comment: This question has been asked in numerous ways already but this is the only answer I have seen, that gives a full and clear answer. There is confusion for some people in understanding the difference between 'app is launched', 'app is in background' and 'app is in foreground'. This answer clearly distinguishes how the app can handle a push notification from the 3 different possible states.

Answer (score 5):

You will receive push notification on following scenarios.

1. **When application is not launched** : Notifications will be shown in notification center and application badge number will update as per notification badge detail. When user tap a notification from notification center, your chat application will be launched with notification info by invoking method **application:didFinishedLaunchWithOptions**. You just need check **options** dictionary for your remoteNotification data.
2. **When application is running in foreground** : You will receive push notifications in 
   **application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:** and you just need to check **userInfo** dictionary for your remote notification data.
3. **When application is running in background** : Notifications will be shown in notification center and application badge number will update as per notification badge detail. When user tap a notification from notification center, your chat application will come to foreground and you will receive user tapped notification in **application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:** and you just need to check **userInfo** dictionary for your remote notification data.

Once you get notification dictionary, you can access **channelId** and present respective chat screen based on received **channelId**.

[Please refer apple doc for handling remote notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW1)