# is it possible to perform an action when Pushnotification received in back ground ios

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I need to perform text to speech when push notification comes.I'm successfully performing text to speech when hitting the notification that we have got.But I want it to implement at the time when it receives notification in back ground .Is it possible or not.

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
  {

  if (launchOptions != nil)
  {

  NSDictionary *notification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];

  ```
  NSLog(@"--------Dictionary%@",notification);

  if (notification) {


      int i=0;
      for (id key in notification)
      {
          NSLog(@"key: %@, value: %@", key, [notification objectForKey:key]);


          if(i==0)
          {
               notificationMessage = [notification objectForKey:key];
          }

          else if (i==1)
          {
              information1=[notification objectForKey:key];
          }

          i++;
      }


      NSString * textToSpeech = [notificationMessage objectForKey:@"alert"];

          [fliteEngine speakText:textToSpeech];   
          [fliteEngine setPitch:100.0 variance:50.0 speed:1.0];
          [fliteEngine setVoice:@"cmu_us_awb"];
  ```

}

Comment: Do you implement `- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didReceiveRemoteNotification: 
(NSDictionary*)userInfo` function in AppDelegate?

Comment: How can I receive data with out implementing that.

Comment: can you please go throughtthe following link where we can do silent push ...refer it and let me know http://hayageek.com/ios-silent-push-notifications/

Comment: i think your requirement query duplicates the other question asked before in other way round. please go through it if useful get it done . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19945419/didreceiveremotenotification-take-user-to-the-correct-view

Comment: @adi Sir, I've followed the link and I sucessfully got notification in background.But I want the notification to speak at the same time.But Text to speech is not working.